# ServiceStack - Message Queue Service (Validation & Filtering)

Tags: c#, servicestack, fluentvalidation

I am new to ServiceStack. I use the Version 4.04.

I created two programs they are using Redis queues to communication to each other.
One is Asp.Net Host the other is a Windows-Service.

While basic sending and receiving messages is working well, I have some problems to configure Validation for request DTOs at the Windows-Service program.

These are my request, response DTOs an the validator:

```
public class RegisterCustomer : IReturn<RegisterCustomerResponse>
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string CompanyName { get; set; }
  public string EMailAddress { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterCustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<RegisterCustomer>
{
  public RegisterCustomerValidator()
  {
    RuleFor(m => m.FirstName).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(m => m.LastName).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(m => m.EMailAddress).NotEmpty().EmailAddress();
    RuleFor(m => m.Password).NotEmpty().Length(5, 100);
  }
}

public class RegisterCustomerResponse
{
  public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

This is the part where I configure the validation:

```
private void configureValidation(Container container)
{
  Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
  // container.RegisterValidators(typeof(RegisterCustomerValidator).Assembly);
  container.Register<IValidator<RegisterCustomer>>(new RegisterCustomerValidator());
}
```

This is my service:

```
public class RegisterCustomerService : RavenService
{
  public RegisterCustomerService(IDocumentSession ravenSession)
    : base(ravenSession)
  {
  }

  public RegisterCustomerResponse Any(RegisterCustomer request)
  {
    Logger.Info("Start: Handel message '{0}' ({1})".Fmt(request.ToString(), request.GetType().Name));

    RegisterCustomerResponse result = new RegisterCustomerResponse();     

    Logger.Info("End: Handel message '{0}' ({1})".Fmt(request.ToString(), request.GetType().Name));
    return result;
  }
}
```

1. The messages & validator are in a seperate assembly located.
   Auto registering the Validator at the IOC via
   `container.RegisterValidators(typeof(RegisterCustomerValidator).Assembly);`
   is not wokring. After I register the Validator via:

`container.Register<IValidator<RegisterCustomer>>(new RegisterCustomerValidator());`

I was able to resolve the Validator at the Service via "TryResolve"

1. I thought as soon as I register the validator at the IOC, the request DTO gets validated. But it looks like that is not the case: The caller gets back the response and the "ResponseStatus" property is null.
2. I created RequestFilter to do the validation:

   public class ValidationFilterAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute
   {
     public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
     {
       string dummy = "HelloWorld";
     }
   }

and applied it to the request dto:

```
[ValidationFilter]
public class RegisterCustomer : IReturn<RegisterCustomerResponse>
{
  ...
}
```

The "Execute" methods is not called. What do I miss here?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use a Request filter like ValidationFilter as the validation should happen automatically. Also surprised container.RegisterValidators doesn't work as that's all I've used and needed. How are you calling your Service? i.e. via C#, Ajax, MQ?

Comment: I update my question to add the answers to your questions.

Comment: I can't update my question!? The validation is working for the Asp.Net Project, but not for the Windows Service Project. The Windows Service Project is only processing messages via the Redis MQ feature. The  AppHost derives from AppHostBase, creates a RedisMqServer and register the message handler via `mqService.RegisterHandler<RegisterCustomer>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was because the validation were getting executed as a Global RequestFilter which aren't executed for [MQ Requests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Architecture-overview) which are considered to be internal services and skip the Global Request Filters.

We've added new `IAppHost.GlobalMessageRequestFilters` in **v4.05** which the ValidationFeature uses to now validate requests via MQ as well.

Note: that any validation or service errors are sent to the Response DLQ (e.g. `QueueNames<RegisterCustomerResponse>.Dlq`) as opposed to the default INQ (e.g. `QueueNames<RegisterCustomerResponse>.Inq`) for valid responses as visible in this example:

```
public class ValidateTestMq
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ValidateTestMqResponse
{
    public int CorrelationId { get; set; }

    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}

public class ValidateTestMqValidator : AbstractValidator<ValidateTestMq>
{
    public ValidateTestMqValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id)
            .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(0)
            .WithErrorCode("PositiveIntegersOnly");
    }
}
```

The test below publishes an invalid request followed by a valid one:

```
using (var mqFactory = appHost.TryResolve<IMessageFactory>())
{
    var request = new ValidateTestMq { Id = -10 };
    mqFactory.CreateMessageProducer().Publish(request);
    var msg = mqFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient()
        .Get(QueueNames<ValidateTestMqResponse>.Dlq, null)
        .ToMessage<ValidateTestMqResponse>();

    Assert.That(msg.GetBody().ResponseStatus.ErrorCode,
        Is.EqualTo("PositiveIntegersOnly"));

    request = new ValidateTestMq { Id = 10 };
    mqFactory.CreateMessageProducer().Publish(request);
    msg = mqFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient()
         .Get(QueueNames<ValidateTestMqResponse>.In, null)
        .ToMessage<ValidateTestMqResponse>();
    Assert.That(msg.GetBody().CorrelationId, Is.EqualTo(request.Id));
}
```

Comment: As soon as I added the filter I get this exception:
    `ServiceBase<TRequest>::Service Exception
    Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein.
    Parametername: key
       bei System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
      bei System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
      bei ServiceStack.ApplyToUtils.HttpMethodAsApplyTo(IRequest req)
      bei ServiceStack.RequestFilterAttribute.RequestFilter(IRequest req, IResponse res, Object requestDto)
      bei ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequest request, Object instance, TRequest requestDto)`

Comment: Your second option is working. Thank you. I thought that the generall behaviour for handling service calls is not depending on how they are used/called (REST vs. MQ).

Comment: @Soernt refer to the Architecture diagram, MQ's are treated as internal requests, the common use-case for Filters is for handling external HTTP logic. I agree that validation is an anomaly, will look to enable that in MQ's as well.

Comment: Your second option is allmost working. When I throw an exception, the service method gets called three times, the callee didn't get any excetion. But if I use it like this       
`RegisterCustomerResponse result = new RegisterCustomerResponse();
      try
      {
        Validate(request);     
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Logger.Error(ex);
        return new RegisterCustomerResponse { ResponseStatus = ex.ToResponseStatus() };
      }
      return result;`
Because neighter of your suggestion is working as you said, I ask myself if something more is wrong within my code.

Comment: @Soernt I'll look into this when I have time, unfortunately I'm boarding a plane to the other side of the world soon, so will likely take a few days to respond.

Comment: @Soernt Hi, I just pushed out a new v4.05 release that executes the validators for MQ requests as well (so you don't need the above work arounds), can you quickly test it out when you have a chance. Note: Invalid requests are sent to the DLQ.

Comment: Thanks for the update! The validator.Validate(...) is called.
I am not so happy that invalid Messages gets into the DLQ. In my case, I set the ReplyTo property while sending the message and waiting for response at that queue. Since my response Dto has a property of type ResponseStatus, I expected that I got back a message with some error messages at that property. The behaviour would be fine if my reponse Dto hasn't such a property.
What do you think about that?

Comment: By design all exceptions go into the DLQ. For the rest, I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. It might need to see a new example to work out if it's expected behavior or not.